# Updating different unique value to each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where everything that has the same classification_id and application_id have the same group_id.

```
id                                  |classification_id                   |application_id                      |authorisation_id                    |group_id                            |
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
54f614f3-7582-4ae9-a07e-5ff6d29e7a3b|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
a01571a1-4f04-4ff9-9a7b-3a720736b9ec|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
3e18f2d0-4d5f-41b3-baf5-ba0feac8f43e|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
b2ebe2ee-ffed-4e32-8abe-cd8b7d400646|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
ef01e6f7-f6ad-4d4d-b129-9c756734bef5|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
7d340811-b679-49fd-bdd6-32a1bb9bbfed|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
c45d7bb6-2146-48d0-a804-929cc42484cd|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
ddec5929-a08f-4f48-97f8-ccc2b85531ac|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
ae9edbb2-def3-4c4e-9a27-72454a09e146|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
3a3fd904-1988-4f8c-bf27-8cdf349b8431|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
27c669b9-763c-49cf-887a-b9b1f85dc1ab|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
03820732-32c4-4cd4-910b-4e27fdd44bdf|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|
```

I've managed to sort out subgroups of this group by authorisation_id and I've created a group_helper which basically shows my end goal - from this data set I want to get three different groups:

```
id                                  |classification_id                   |application_id                      |authorisation_id                    |group_id                            |group_helper|
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+
54f614f3-7582-4ae9-a07e-5ff6d29e7a3b|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           2|
a01571a1-4f04-4ff9-9a7b-3a720736b9ec|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           2|
3e18f2d0-4d5f-41b3-baf5-ba0feac8f43e|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           2|
b2ebe2ee-ffed-4e32-8abe-cd8b7d400646|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           2|
ef01e6f7-f6ad-4d4d-b129-9c756734bef5|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           3|
7d340811-b679-49fd-bdd6-32a1bb9bbfed|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           3|
c45d7bb6-2146-48d0-a804-929cc42484cd|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           3|
ddec5929-a08f-4f48-97f8-ccc2b85531ac|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|           3|
ae9edbb2-def3-4c4e-9a27-72454a09e146|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
3a3fd904-1988-4f8c-bf27-8cdf349b8431|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
27c669b9-763c-49cf-887a-b9b1f85dc1ab|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
03820732-32c4-4cd4-910b-4e27fdd44bdf|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
```

Now, I want each of those groups to have a different group_id. I don't have to update the one which has group_id = NULL since it is already unique. Now I want to give every row that has group_helper  = 2 same (but different from those where group_id = NULL) UUID, every row that has group_helper = 3 same UUID (but different from those which have group_id = NULL or 2) and so on. This has to work on n amount of group_helper values because there can be much more than maximum 2.

So my end goal would look like this:

```
id                                  |classification_id                   |application_id                      |authorisation_id                    |group_id                            |group_helper|
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+
54f614f3-7582-4ae9-a07e-5ff6d29e7a3b|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|fd3e63d1-d59c-477f-b58b-3ae3726c7992|           2|
a01571a1-4f04-4ff9-9a7b-3a720736b9ec|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|fd3e63d1-d59c-477f-b58b-3ae3726c7992|           2|
3e18f2d0-4d5f-41b3-baf5-ba0feac8f43e|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|fd3e63d1-d59c-477f-b58b-3ae3726c7992|           2|
b2ebe2ee-ffed-4e32-8abe-cd8b7d400646|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|fd3e63d1-d59c-477f-b58b-3ae3726c7992|           2|
ef01e6f7-f6ad-4d4d-b129-9c756734bef5|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|ed3ff96c-2f93-4182-8e4f-4594cb20cbb6|           3|
7d340811-b679-49fd-bdd6-32a1bb9bbfed|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|ed3ff96c-2f93-4182-8e4f-4594cb20cbb6|           3|
c45d7bb6-2146-48d0-a804-929cc42484cd|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|ed3ff96c-2f93-4182-8e4f-4594cb20cbb6|           3|
ddec5929-a08f-4f48-97f8-ccc2b85531ac|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|ed3ff96c-2f93-4182-8e4f-4594cb20cbb6|           3|
ae9edbb2-def3-4c4e-9a27-72454a09e146|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|a4edd12d-c19e-4e0d-badd-d3cf5e6d6d82|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
3a3fd904-1988-4f8c-bf27-8cdf349b8431|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|25a7e1f7-4d8c-4e12-a10f-3654d7ef5ee9|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
27c669b9-763c-49cf-887a-b9b1f85dc1ab|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|302b23f1-ce57-4219-bcae-7bdbc3b86cb4|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
03820732-32c4-4cd4-910b-4e27fdd44bdf|63a7b151-2b8d-4b6a-b9a1-108a80ae4cdf|cd3d597b-25d1-4b4b-92f0-2ad8fcb4698c|5e3bce60-b0d8-436c-9d33-b3a1d4c9a308|8e563f95-ff0c-41e7-b211-d5ac6f78d056|            |
```

Comment: Guids don't make for easy reading, substituting with integers for the purpose of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a CTE which generates new `group_id`, selecting a single value for each `group_helper` column, then use `update ... from ...`.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d69ec7b8ffd5a06d6dd2819946769adf0))

```
with grouper(helper, gid) as 
     (select distinct on (group_helper)
              group_helper
            , gen_random_uuid() 
         from sometable
        where group_helper is not null 
        order by group_helper
     ) --select * from grouper
update sometable
   set group_id = gid 
  from grouper 
 where helper = group_helper;
```